# Fido2 implementation in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webauthn, fido

I am implementing the fido2 (WebAuthn) authentication in my iOS and Android app that is built on React Native. I am using React-native-fido2 library for it. The RN library uses Google Fido2 api for android and a third party library for iOS.

The link for iOS libary: https://github.com/lyokato/WebAuthnKit-iOS

The RN library: https://github.com/Emad-salah/react-native-fido

The problem is the React Native library has no proper documentation to implement, but I tried to figure out the usage of android by seeing the Google's Fido2 api, but having problem implementing the iOS part, as it throws error that this operation can not be completed.

Is there anyone who implemented this using the React Native Library or can help me by giving a documentation or a ReadME to properly implement it?

Answer (score 0):

We used SFSafariViewController for FIDO2 authentication in swift code which has the support of the WebAuthN javascript component.

I see SFSafariView Controller can be leveraged to reach native projects, please visit the Github project link to add support of SFSafariViewController https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32500664)